# Mysql tmp_table_size max_heap_table_size

Tags: mysql

On my server 2 days ago my `tmp_table_size` = `max_heap_table_size(16M)`.

I made a cron job that runs once an hour and generates a report starting from : `created_tmp_disk_tables`, `created_tmp_files`, `created_tmp_tables`

In my report : `created_tmp_disk_tables`+`created_tmp_files`+`created_tmp_tables`=100% of my temporary data

With that :

1. with `tmp_table_size`=`max_heap_table_size`=`16M` the report showed me the next average report:

   - 27.37% (created_tmp_disk_tables)
   - 1.16% (created_tmp_files)
   - 71.48% (created_tmp_tables)

How can I optimize these results?

2. with `tmp_table_size`=`max_heap_table_size`=`20M` in the first hour :

   - 23.48% (created_tmp_disk_tables)
   - 32.44% (created_tmp_files)
   - 44.07% (created_tmp_tables)

After 7 hours (from restart):

- 21.70% (created_tmp_disk_tables)
- 33.75% (created_tmp_files)
- 44.55% (created_tmp_tables)

It's not what I expected.

- disk tables decreased from `27.37%` to `21.70%` -> expected much more
- temporary files rise form `1.16%` to `33.75%`  -> why ?
- memory tables decreased from `71.48%` to `44.55%` -> strange; expected to rise

Answer (score 196):

Whenever you increase [**tmp_table_size**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_tmp_table_size) and [**max_heap_table_size**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_heap_table_size), keep in mind that setting these does not make queries behave better. It actually make inefficient queries behave worse than before. Under what circumstances?

When a query performs a join or sort (via `ORDER BY`) without the benefit of an index, a temp table has to be formed in memory. This would increment [**Created_tmp_tables**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Created_tmp_tables).

What if the temp table grows to the number of bytes in [**tmp_table_size**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_tmp_table_size) and needs more space? The following sequence of events happens:

1. Query processing must stop
2. Create a temp table on disk
3. Transfer the contents of the memory-based temp table into the disk-based temp table
4. Drop in the memory-based temp table
5. Query processing continue using the disk-based temp table

This process increments [**Created_tmp_disk_tables**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Created_tmp_disk_tables)

Knowing these mechanisms, let's explore what happened in each instance

> disk tables decreased from 27.37% to 21.70% -> expected much more

This could easily happen if the queries that ran before have cached results remaining in RAM. This would eliminate the need to process the query from the beginning and not recreate the same large temp tables.

> temporary files rise form 1.16% to 33.75% -> why ?

This is not surprising. This simply brings out the fact that there are queries that require temp tables. They were created in RAM first. This just indicates the presence of queries that do not join well (maybe [**join_buffer_size**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_join_buffer_size) is too small) or `ORDER BY` non-indexed columns or columns with a temp table (maybe [**sort_buffer_size**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sort_buffer_size) is too small).

> memory tables decreased from 71.48% to 44.55% -> strange; expected to rise

This is not surprising either. If there are enough calls for the same query with the same values, sorts and joins may be preempted by the fulfillment of queries from previously cached results.

## RECOMMENDATION

In light of these things, here is what could be adjusted:

- [join_buffer_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_join_buffer_size)
- [sort_buffer_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sort_buffer_size)
- Create indexes that would be used

  - in joins via eq_ref
  - in sorts via index scans in order

The overall goal should be to prevent temp table creation as much as possible. Simply increasing [**tmp_table_size**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_tmp_table_size) and [**max_heap_table_size**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_heap_table_size) lets inefficient queries and tables that lack proper indexing run amok.

Comment: This is an excellent and trustworthy answer. Just a note to anyone that finds themself here.